# 'dataframe' object has no attribute 'str' problem for the whole DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 13 columns and I would like to remove text before specific character in every column (same character, existing in all columns).

If for one only column I use the following: `DataFrame.ColumnA.str.split('\:').str[-1].str.strip()` it successfully removes the text before the ":".

However, and where my problem is, when I try to do that for two or more columns, e.g.: `DataFrame[['ColumnA','ColumnB']].str.split('\:').str[-1].str.strip()`
then I receive the following message:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

If it is of any help, when creating the columns I used the following:  `DataFrame.columns = headerName`, in which `headerName` i entered the names of the columns, trying to avoid any  MultiIndex object issues.

My ultimate goal is to apply this command for the whole dataframe of 13 columns.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
DataFrame[['ColumnA','ColumnB']].apply(lambda s: s.str.split('\:').str[-1].str.strip())
```

Or a list comprehension, which can be significantly faster as chaining `str` methods can be slow:

```
[[s.split('\:')[-1].strip() for s in df[col]] for col in ['ColumnA','ColumnB']]
```